# MultiThreading in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, winforms, stored-procedures

I am newbie and i learned alot of things from StackOverflow. I recently started using threading in my windows application. As far as i heard multi-threading makes things easy, like doing alot of event at the same time.

I have Stored procedures in SQL and I call then in few methods.

here is my code

```
private void EditCustomer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            screenszize_Location();

            Thread BackgroundThread = new Thread
                (
                new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    GridCustomerList.BeginInvoke(
                     new Action(() =>
                     {
                         LoadGrid();
                     }
                     ));
                }

                ));
            BackgroundThread.Start();


            Thread BackgroundThread1 = new Thread
                (
                new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    ComboBxVechicleNumber.BeginInvoke(
                     new Action(() =>
                     {
                         LoadVnum();
                     }
                     ));
                }


                ));
            BackgroundThread1.Start();

            Thread BackgroundThread2 = new Thread
                (
                new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    ComboBxBikeMake.BeginInvoke(
                     new Action(() =>
                     {
                         loadBikeMake();
                     }
                     ));
                }


                ));
            BackgroundThread2.Start();

        }
```

What this does is, 
 * Screen Layout
 * Loads a 3 column Grid wit some 2000 rows
 * Loads Vehicle numbers from SQL table into a Combobox.
 * Loads Bike Names from SQL table into a Combobox.

My Computer is fast has best performance, but still The Form which i load freezes and becomes WHITE for couple of seconds and then a loads.

[image: Please Check the image and you can see the freezer screen]

Am I doing the whole threading thing wrong ?

Comment: you start new thread just to pass execution to UI thread via `BeginInvoke`

Comment: What you are doing with the code you posted is that in your UI thread you create a thread that delegates the work back on the UI thread. You might as well do the work in the `EditCustomer_Load` method. What you probably wanted to do was to load the data from the database in a seperate thread and then invoke a method on the UI thread to display the data.

Comment: @Drik "Actually the `EditCustomer_Load` is the FormLoad Method

Comment: @Dirk , So what if i put the actual code in the thread

i.e . . removing `LoadGrid()` and putting the actual code

Comment: The `LoadGrid` method is invoked on the UI thread. You should do the work that takes long but doesn't require access to UI elements *before* the call to `GridCustomerList.BeginInvoke`.

Comment: But Drik if i dont use BeginInvoke it give me an error like

**InvalidOperationException was unhandled:
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'GridCustomerList' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on**

i follwed this document

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/449594/Progress-Bars-Threads-Windows-Forms-and-You

Comment: Again. read what he says. He says load the data in the thread then invoke back to the UI to put the data into the control. Iny modern C' though (not totally outdated) you would better use async than threading here.

Comment: "As far as i heard multi-threading makes things easy." This sentence is, unfortunately, just wrong. It may make things faster, but multithreading _improves_ the complexity of the application and there are many subtle and hard-to-find bugs you can introduce using it.

Comment: @PMF ...Thank You for correcting my sentence, i got all the time to deal with the bugs :D. Anyow thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your LoadGrid method definition, but I guess it fetches data from the DB, and then sets the DataSource on a DataGridView or BindingSource.

You should split those 2 steps such that only the setting of the DataSource is done on the UI thread, and the fetching of the data still happens in the BackgroundThread.

Something like this:

```
Thread BackgroundThread = new Thread
(
new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    //Fetch data here
    GridCustomerList.BeginInvoke(
     new Action(() =>
     {
         //Set DataSource here
     }
     ));
}

));
```

Cheers

Comment: Thankzz for making it Clear :) I will tried it right away. And its working :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @mrlucmorin and Drik and TomTom and Every1

Hea is My Code Again.

```
private void LoadGrid()
        {
            Thread BackgroundThread = new Thread
                (
                new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    ConnectionStringSettings consetting = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AutoDB"];

                         String ConnectionString = consetting.ConnectionString;

                         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

                             SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

                             int i = 0;

                             con.Open();
                             command.Connection = con;
                             command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                             command.CommandText = "LoadAllCustomers";


                             da.SelectCommand = command;
                             da.Fill(ds, "dbo.TblCustomers");

                    GridCustomerList.BeginInvoke(
                     new Action(() =>
                     {

                         GridCustomerList.DataSource = ds.Tables["dbo.TblCustomers"];

                     }
                     ));
                }

                ));
            BackgroundThread.Start();


        }
```

It works Perfectly as expected :)